# I want to select an item in a dropdown list but the id of the dropdown list change with every run

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I want to select an item in a dropdown list but the id of the dropdown list change with every run.   This is the element code: `<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="TableName_c2937ec1-50e5-4df6-b2e1-8a9c0a2b3f9f_listbox" aria-live="polite" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox"><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" aria-selected="false" data-offset-index="0">CaseCmsCustomerDto</li>`

My Code

```
IWebElement fltTableNm = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/fieldset[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/span"));
            fltTableNm.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            IWebElement slctfltTableNm = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//id=[starts-with(.,'TableName')]/li[1]"));
            slctfltTableNm.Click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this xpath? Your idea is right, the id is dynamic but contains something unique enough to go on.
Your xpath misses the //ul and starts-with wirks like this:

```
IWebElement slctfltTableNm = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[starts-with(@id,'TableName')]/li[1]"));
```

Or
By.XPath("//ul[@class='k-list k-reset']/li[1]